# Neo4j PHP OGM with Authentication

Tags: neo4j, graphaware, neo4j-php-ogm

I was wondering: what is the best practice to create a connection to Neo4j through the neo4j-php-ogm library if I am using username and password authentication?

In the documentation it states that connections are created by following:

```
use GraphAware\Neo4j\OGM\EntityManager;
$manager = EntityManager::create('http://localhost:7474');
```

So I am using the same in my graph manager:

```
$client = Manager::create('http://username:password@localhost:7474');
```

I have a feeling that this is not the safest way because I am only using http and sending the credentials in the URL. What would be a better way to establish a connection including authentication?

Sidenote: The `Manager::create` instead of the `EntityManager::create` as noted in the documentation is because installing the library via composer gets an older version than currently on GitHub if im not mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just provide them as part of the uri defined for your connection :

```
$manager = EntityManager::create('http://neo4j:password@localhost:7474');
```

Note that there are not sent as such for security reasons, instead the username and password are extracted with `parse_url` and provided as connection parameters.

For the second part, yes the current 1.0 branch reflects changes that are not tagged yet. I should make a new beta release this week.

Comment: Thanks Christophe for the fast answer! Maybe it would be a good idea to mention this (authentication) in the documentation? I have once again started an attempt to create a Neo4jUserBundle for Symfony using your new neo4j-php-ogm, if interested I will let you know when I have a working bundle.

Comment: Thanks ! I think things will get easier for you know for the symfony bundle.

Comment: Please please let me know how it goes

Comment: @Joran I have released the 1.0.0-beta3 with some improvements and the EntityManager instead of Manager

Comment: Perfect! Now running as documented. FYI: Registration and login are working, now creating profile, password reset and so on. Two quick questions: Can I use "AND"/"OR" in "findOneBy()"/"findBy()"? Can I send raw cypher queries or should I use another library for this? I need to integrate Neo4j spatial in my project.

Comment: @Joran Currently no OR/AND possible. You can use custom cypher queries in repositories with QueryResult classes, please open an issue on the repo or contact me by email christophe at graphaware dot com

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have now uploaded a bundle to GitHub (working for me): https://github.com/JoranBeaufort/Neo4jUserBundle. In the next few weeks I will try to add spatial functions to your OGM. Annotations like `@OGM\Property(type="point")` or `@OGM\Property(type="linestring")` might be the way to go...

Comment: @Joran cool, this week I should work on lazy loaded relationships, so stay tuned ;-)